# using smart select in gorm with many 2 many relation

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to use smart select when querying rooms table. When use the original struct it works fine but when use smart select it fails.
Here is my schema

```
type Room struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID       uint      `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Hash     string    `json:"hash" binding:"required" gorm:"not null:true"`
    Users    []User    `json:"users" gorm:"many2many:room_users"`
    Messages []Message `json:"messages"`
}

type RoomAPI struct {
    ID    uint   `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Hash  string `json:"hash" binding:"required" gorm:"not null:true"`
    Users []User `json:"users" gorm:"many2many:room_users"`
    //Messages []Message `json:"messages" gorm:"foreignKey:RoomID"`
}

func (RoomAPI) TableName() string {
    return "rooms"
}

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID       uint   `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name     string `json:"name" binding:"required" gorm:"not null:true"`
    Phone    string `json:"phone"`
    Email    string `json:"email" binding:"required,email" gorm:"not null:true"`
    Password string `json:"password" binding:"required,min=8" gorm:"not null:true"`
    Gender   string `json:"gender" binding:"Enum=male_female" gorm:"type:gender;not null:true;default:male"`
    Rooms    []Room `json:"rooms" gorm:"many2many:room_users"`
}

type Message struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID     uint   `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Text   string `json:"text" binding:"required" gorm:"not null:true"`
    UserID uint   `json:"user_id" gorm:"not null:true"`
    RoomID uint   `json:"room_id" gorm:"not null:true"`
}
```

here is my query

```
    var rooms []RoomAPI
    user := User{ID: userId}
    err := db.DB.Model(&user).Preload("Users").
        Association("Rooms").
        Find(&rooms)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("err -> %+v", err)
        return err, nil
    }
    return nil, rooms
```

I want to get rooms with selected fields with smart select but it fails

Comment: associations cause problems with primary keys. have you tried Preload("Users.Rooms")?

Comment: @Anni yes but didn't solve the problem